# Write vertically

Tags: chemfig, vertical

I'm writing the tetrahydrate copper complex ion

```
\chemleft[
\chemfig{H_2\lewis{1:7:,O}-[,,,,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt]\ce{Cu}([:90]-\lewis{5:7:,O}([:90,0.5]-H_2))([:-90]-[,,,,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt]\lewis{3:1:,O}([:-90,0.5]-H_2))-\lewis{3:5:,O}H_2}
\chemright]
```

[image]

How can I get away the bond between hydrogen and oxygen on the water molecules in vertical position? Otherwise, is there a way to write from top to bottom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first relevant part of the `chemfig` manual to answer this question is part III section 1 *Separating atoms*:

> The character “`|`” forces splitting of the atom when it is encountered.
>   Thus we can write `C|{(CH_3)_3}` to ensure that ChemFig separates just
>   two atoms here: “`C`” and “`{(CH_3)_3}`”.

Applied to your problem at hand this means change the vertical `H_2` into `H|_2`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\chemleft[
  \chemfig{
    H_2\lewis{1:7:,O}-[,,,,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt]Cu
      ([:90]-\lewis{5:7:,O}([:90,0.5]-H|_2))
      ([:-90]-[,,,,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt]\lewis{3:1:,O}([:-90,0.5]-H|_2))
      -\lewis{3:5:,O}H_2
  }
\chemright]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The second relevant part is found in part II section 6 *Customization of bonds*:

> There is a fifth and last optional argument for bonds which is found
>   after the fourth comma:
>
> ```
> [,,,,<tikz code>]
> ```

You can use the TikZ argument of the bonds to make the bonds invisible. Furthermore you can shorten the distance by using a smaller factor (*e.g.* 0.3 instead of 0.5):

```
(-[:90,0.3,,,draw=none]H|_2)
```

Applying this to both groups gives

[image]